How can current still exists as t approaches infinity in RL circuit
The textbook solution for  \$b)\ (\ i_{o}(t),t\geq 0\ ) \$ is $$\  1.25e^{-1500t}-1.25A,$$
but as \$t\$ approaches infinity, the current will be \$-1.25A \$ for \$i_{o} \$.
How can this be possible, if there is no power source in the circuit after the switch is closed?
On top of this question, why can't I use the general solution for step and natural responses to solve for \$b)i_{o} \$.


Note that this is a theoretical circuit because inductors are ideal. The current in the resistor and 1025 H disappears rapidly so currents across inductors 6 H and 10 H are equal but opposite.

Actually, I'm kind of curious how there is $i_0\ne 0$ when the switch above it is open for all that time while $t\lt 0$. No place for it to go while its switch has been in its indicated position for a long time. Just an open end there.

An ideal inductor that is carrying current will keep on carrying that current for an infinite length of time when it is disconnected from the power source and shorted out. There is no power input required to maintain this current because no power is dissipated.
In other words, an ideal inductor can store energy for ever when shorted out just as an ideal capacitor can store energy when open-circuited.

How can current still exists as t approaches infinity in RL circuit

It's not an "RL" circuit anymore; it's an "L" circuit. The presence of the 7.5 kΩ resistor is irrelevant.

Note that this is a theoretical circuit because inductors are ideal.
The current in the resistor and 1.25 H disappears rapidly so currents across inductors 6 H and 10 H are equal but opposite.

